# Salesforce API for getting all case comments from Case ID

Tags: rest-api, case, salesforce-id, sobjectfield, case-comment

I am new to Salesforce and using its API for getting comments. I am getting resource id like of Case, Feed or Idea I need to get its CaseComment, FeedComment, and IdeaComment. I am requesting Resource details like,
https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000oGq8CAAS

I am getting ID of case, feed or idea like, **5002800000oGq8CAAS**

I want all comments of Case is that possible to get so?

any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: I believe as of now there is no direct way available to do that. You can try SOQL over REST API or build your own custom REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can call an API like this to get related stuff. 
https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000oGq8CAAS/CaseComments